# Display all groups on 1 page instead of 30 per page.

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, groups

I'm trying to find all groups in a site and their users. We don't have access to the server so I can't run any scripts to get that information. I know how to find all the groups but the page shows them by 30, which slows me down if I need to do a quick search. Is there anyway I can change it to get all the groups to display on one page. Or if anyone knows of a way I can get all the groups and users from the front-end, that would be pretty amazing also. I know AvePoint has some software that would make all this a million time easier, it's just not an option for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

The Site Users web part (in the "Social Collaboration" category) might get you what you want and can be added to any web part page with a configurable maximum number to display.

Comment: Is there a way to group by Groups. My main problem is accessing all groups and then users within the groups. A list of all users won't really help unless I can group it by which groups they belong too. Plus considering some users belong to multiple gorups, I don't think this would work out unfortunately. EDIT: the more i play with the webpart settinngs the more i think you may be on to something :)

Comment: On my site, it is only showing groups; I think it would only show users who are granted permissions directly to the site (rather than via group membership).

Comment: Yea that what I noticed. It's actually a really good solution. The only problem is that I can't have this webpart being displayed on the site collection where everyone lands. There's 380 users, 181 groups, and very sensitive info. But if I move the webpart to a more restricted site, it will only give me groups for that site and not the site collection :/

Comment: @Batman Why not set permissions on the page with this webpart?

Comment: @JamesFlattery I don't remember what this issue was anymore but yea sure that would probably work.